# I have a problem with the implementing a try and catch block on Java, could I have some advice on how to go about it?

Tags: java, arrays, input, try-catch

I was given the task of splitting my program which allows the user to enter an array of numbers and after an odd number between 1 and 10 to check whether the odd number is a factor of each of the 5 numbers in the array. I'm having a problem with the validation as I am required to use a try and catch block to check for anything wrong in the input stage. Could someone help me out? This is the program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CheckboxExample{  
    public static void main(String args[])  {  
        CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
        new CheckboxExample();  // links to checkbox class
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int array[] = new int[10]; 
        System.out.println ("Please enter 10 random numbers"); // prompts the user to enter 10 numbers
        int num; // declares variable num
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            array[i] = s.nextInt(); // array declaration
        }
        
        
        System.out.println ("Please enter an odd number between 1 and 10");
        num = s.nextInt ();

        if (num % 2 == 0){
            do{
                System.out.println ("\nYour number is even, enter an odd one");
                num = s.nextInt ();
            }while (num % 2 == 0);
        } 

        if (num < 0 & num > 10){
            do{  
                System.out.println ("Your number is outside of the range, try again");
                num = s.nextInt ();  
            }while (num < 0 & num > 10);
        } 

        for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++){
            if (array[i] % num  == 0) {
                System.out.println("Your number is a factor of " + array[i] );
            } 
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to do a try catch, I will demonstrate with a sysout.

```
public class Main
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(args[0]);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Please add an argument!");
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully that explained how to make a try-catch, but just to let you know if you are looking for NullPointerExceptions it is usually more accepted to use an if statement.